# OpenMP parallelize but not accelerate code

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, thread-safety, openmp

I've been trying to accelerate the following code

```
void calcstiffTestOMP(TPZCompMesh *cmesh,int nthread){
    int64_t nelem = cmesh->NElements();
    omp_set_num_threads(nthread);

    auto beginCalcStiff = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int s=0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:s)
    for (int64_t iel = 0; iel < nelem; iel++)
    {
        TPZCompEl *el = cmesh->Element(iel);
        if (!el) continue;
        TPZElementMatrix ek(cmesh, TPZElementMatrix::EK), ef(cmesh, TPZElementMatrix::EF);
        el->CalcStiff(ek, ef);
    }
    auto endCalcStiff = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(endCalcStiff - beginCalcStiff);
    unsigned long int duration = static_cast<unsigned long int>(elapsed.count());
    std::cout << " CalcStiff parallel duration omp = " << duration*1E-9 << " seconds, with nthreads= " << nthread << std::endl;
}
```

but the simulation time hasn't changed, independently of the number of threads.
The same code has been accelerated when using TBB directives, as follows

```
void calcstiffTestTBB(TPZCompMesh *cmesh,int nthread){
    auto beginCalcStiff = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    int64_t nelem = cmesh->NElements();
    tbb::task_scheduler_init init(nthread);
    tbb::parallel_for( tbb::blocked_range<int64_t>(0,nelem),
                      [&](tbb::blocked_range<int64_t> r){
    for (int64_t iel = r.begin(); iel < r.end(); iel++)
    {
        TPZCompEl *el = cmesh->Element(iel);
        if (!el) continue;
        TPZElementMatrix ek(cmesh, TPZElementMatrix::EK), ef(cmesh, TPZElementMatrix::EF);

        el->CalcStiff(ek, ef);
    }
    });
    auto endCalcStiff = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(endCalcStiff - beginCalcStiff);
    unsigned long int duration = static_cast<unsigned long int>(elapsed.count());
    std::cout << " CalcStiff duration tbb= " << duration*1E-9 << " seconds, with nthreads= "<<nthread << std::endl;
}
```

The calcstiff function is given by:

```
void TPZMultiphysicsCompEl<TGeometry>::CalcStiff(TPZElementMatrix &ek, TPZElementMatrix &ef)
{
    TPZMaterial * material = Material();
    if(!material){
        PZError << "Error at " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " this->Material() == NULL\n";
        ek.Reset();
        ef.Reset();
        return;
    }
    
    TPZNullMaterial *nullmat = dynamic_cast<TPZNullMaterial *>(material);
    if(nullmat)
    {
        ek.Reset();
        ef.Reset();
        ek.fType = TPZElementMatrix::EK;
        ef.fType = TPZElementMatrix::EF;
        return;
    }
    InitializeElementMatrix(ek,ef);
    
    if (this->NConnects() == 0) return;//boundary discontinuous elements have this characteristic
    
    TPZManVector<TPZMaterialData,6> datavec;
    const int64_t nref = fElementVec.size();
    datavec.resize(nref);
    InitMaterialData(datavec);
    
    TPZManVector<TPZTransform<> > trvec;
    AffineTransform(trvec);
    
    int dim = Dimension();
    TPZAutoPointer<TPZIntPoints> intrule;
    
    TPZManVector<REAL,4> intpointtemp(TGeometry::Dimension,0.);
    REAL weight = 0.;
    
    TPZManVector<int,4> ordervec;
    //ordervec.resize(nref);
    for (int64_t iref=0;  iref<nref; iref++)
    {
        TPZInterpolationSpace *msp  = dynamic_cast <TPZInterpolationSpace *>(fElementVec[iref].Element());
        int svec;
        if(msp)
        {
            ordervec.Resize(ordervec.size()+1);
            svec = ordervec.size();
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
        datavec[iref].p =1; //msp->MaxOrder();
        ordervec[svec-1] = datavec[iref].p;
    }
    int order = material->IntegrationRuleOrder(ordervec);
    
    TPZGeoEl *ref = this->Reference();
    intrule = ref->CreateSideIntegrationRule(ref->NSides()-1, order);
    
    TPZManVector<int,4> intorder(dim,order);
    intrule->SetOrder(intorder);
    int intrulepoints = intrule->NPoints();
    if(intrulepoints > 1000) {
        DebugStop();
    }
    
    TPZFMatrix<REAL> jac, axe, jacInv;
    REAL detJac;
    for(int int_ind = 0; int_ind < intrulepoints; ++int_ind)
    {
        intrule->Point(int_ind,intpointtemp,weight);
        ref->Jacobian(intpointtemp, jac, axe, detJac , jacInv);
        weight *= fabs(detJac);
        for (int i = 0; i < fElementVec.size(); i++) {
            TPZInterpolationSpace *msp  = dynamic_cast <TPZInterpolationSpace *>(fElementVec[i].Element());
            if (!msp) {
                continue;
            }
            datavec[i].intLocPtIndex = int_ind;
        }
        
        this->ComputeRequiredData(intpointtemp,trvec,datavec);
        

    
       material->Contribute(datavec,weight,ek.fMat,ef.fMat);
        

        }//loop over integration points
    
    CleanupMaterialData(datavec);
}
```

The code has been parallelized but not accelerated. Are we using omp directives correctly?
Does OMP create mutex sections on its own? Is there a better way to parallelize this code using OMP?

PZ is a library which serve as a template for finite element code, and can be found in https://github.com/labmec/neopz

SOLUTION: Adding the 'schedule(dynamic,1)'  flag to '#pragma' directive solved this problem. The code had different thread workloads
and OMP was using a single thread to handle the slow section of the loop. The 'schedule(dynamic,1)' directive solved this.

Comment: You use `reduction(+:s)` but `s` is not affected in the first loop (which is non conforming to the OpenMP standard)... `high_resolution_clock` is not a good clock for this. Please use `steady_clock`. Are you sure the function called are *thread-safe*? What is the execution time of the resulting code (eg. minute, seconds, ms, us) ?

Comment: OpenMP doesn't automatically create mutexes. For that you should use `#pragma omp critical` or if possible `#pragma omp atomic`. See [here](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf) (6.1 and 6.4) how to use them. There is also lock routines (6.9), but they shouldn't be used if you can avoid it as they are more low-level.